# What is the difference between 'git --help' and 'git help'?

Tags: git

in the documentation from git they say this :

> Other options are available to control how the manual page is displayed. See git-help[1](https://git-scm.com/docs/git) for more information, because git --help ... is converted internally into git help

I understand that a option give me more info with details but how working each one?

what are the benefits of use to each one?

[git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`git help help`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-help), or `git --help help` :), answers the question:

> ... `git --help ...` is **identical** to `git help ...` ... *the former is internally converted into the latter*.

Comment: they are identical?  it does not exist some  different between their?

Comment: @Simon The output of both is the same, if you type `git --help` it will be converted into `git help`.